# modernizer-maven-plugin Joda Instant

Tags: java, jodatime, static-code-analysis, java.time.instant, modernizer-maven-plugin

I am trying to construct an org.joda.time.Instant from a LocalDate. Ordinarily it is as simple as;

```
new org.joda.time.Instant(myDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

But the project I am working on uses the modernizer-maven-plugin and there is a violation on Prefer java.time.Instant. I am not able to change the API of the class I am attempting to use.

So, my question is how do "Prefer java.time.Instant"?

Thx

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: If I read the page on [Modernizer Maven Plugin](https://github.com/gaul/modernizer-maven-plugin) correctly, there are some ways to exclude instances of use of legacy API. If you need to use an API that requires a Joda-Time `Instant`,  I suggest that this is what you need to do. Your code is fine IMHO.

Comment: Yeah, in the end I had to make an exclusion for this code. Apparently there is a method of InstantConverter but I could not figure it out.

Comment: If you need an instance of `org.joda.time.Instant`, I wouldn’t expect that `InstantConverter` would help stop the modernizer complaining. I encourage you to post an answer to your own question to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable specific instances of Modernizer violations via the `@SuppressModernizer` annotation:

https://github.com/gaul/modernizer-maven-plugin#ignoring-elements

To ignore all instances of a violation, you can add an `<exclusions>` stanza similar to:

```xml
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>org/joda/time/Instant.now:()Lorg/joda/time/Instant;</exclusion>
    <exclusion>org/joda/time/Instant.parse:(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/joda/time/Instant;</exclusion>
    <exclusion>org/joda/time/Instant."&lt;init&gt;":(J)V</exclusion>
</exclusions>
```